# Anchor not working with overflow hidden [Microsoft Edge]

Tags: html, css, overflow, microsoft-edge

Edge probably doesn't want to scroll onto something that isn't visible. If an anchor element is outside of his parent dimensions with overflow: hidden, Edge browser will not scroll onto that.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#anchor {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px; /* if you change back to 0, anchor will work */
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box first">
  <a href="#anchor">GO TO ANCHOR IN SECOND SECTION</a>
</div>

<div class="box second">
  <div id="anchor"></div>
</div>
```

I need an anchor that is outside of his parent which has overflow: hidden, while href still scrolls on anchor.

It works fine on Chrome and Firefox.
Edge version: 44.17763.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty weird and I can't tell you why Edge does it. However, a quick-fix for your example is to have one row of invisible pixels rendered, by adding

```
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; /* this will overlap the parent element */
 background-clip: content-box; /* bg is not painted under border */
```

See it [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ve5yc9qL/). As you can see, Edge plays along.

Comment: Good idea! But you still can't reach the same behaviour as on Chrome or Firefox. Because in order for that to work, you have to give anchor same for height and top attribute. This results in only being able to scroll at the beggining of anchor parent, but you can't scroll for example 60 pixels before the parent. This is problem if you have 60px navigation and you need to scroll 60px BEFORE the element :/

Comment: Just noticed it works fine in your example when I delete height but in my more complex code it isn't working.

Comment: That's at least debatable and my impression is that Edge has got this one right. If the parent has `overflow: hidden` it means ***everything happening inside it stays inside it***. Therefore the point you're trying to scroll to does not exist in the document space, because it's outside of an element with `overflow:hidden`. The proper way to solve this is to put the anchor inside the visible space of the parent, not outside of it and give the parent a negative top margin equal to the anchor's height. That will work cross browser and would be a correct approach, IMHO.

Comment: On one hand I agree, on the other hand - I don't think it's good approach to put anchor for section #2 to section #1. That's a bit confusing.